# How To Select / Export only Visible Features in Qgis

Tags: python, mapping, qgis

i have a layer contains of cities name, i want to make a small size map, so not all the cities name are able to shown in the map, i want to export / select only the visible cities name that are only shown in the map, how can i do that?

i tried using right click on the layer and select "**open attribute table**" and then i use filter "**show features visible on map**" after that i tried to select them all, but it is also select the all non visible features.

how to select all, but only visible features? so i can export it to seperate file.

thank you.